# Library containing dictionary definitions

Tags: dictionary

I'm looking for some sort of library (preferably .NET, XML, or JSON) that can provide me with words and their definitions. But, I would prefer for it to be local on my machine. I've looked into the Webster's online API, but again, I would prefer it to be local on my machine and also not have the limitations.

I'd like to think that there probably something already on my Windows pc that I could just tap into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordNet from Princeton:
"WordNet® is a large lexical database of English. Nouns, verbs, adjectives and adverbs are grouped into sets of cognitive synonyms (synsets), each expressing a distinct concept. Synsets are interlinked by means of conceptual-semantic and lexical relations. The resulting network of meaningfully related words and concepts can be navigated with the browser. WordNet is also freely and publicly available for download. WordNet's structure makes it a useful tool for computational linguistics and natural language processing."
http://wordnet.princeton.edu/