# Grouped vocabulary list as .txt or .csv files

Tags: data-request, csv, dictionary, txt

I'm working on a project with email data.And simply i need to group up all the emails according to suitable categories. Therefore, i use the dictionary mapping method. So,

### My project required lots of word/vocabularies related to categories like Business, Academic, technology, personal ,political, entertainment and so on.

I found few websites(eg:[like](http://www.easypacelearning.com/english-books/big-vocabulary-list-a-to-z)) its provide words around 20-50 for each categories. i'm looking for little large data set to increase my accuracy of classifying. any help appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`WordData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WordData.html) function with the `"UsageField"` property in Wolfram Mathematica. Expand the **Details** section for more properties.

```
WordData["litigation", "UsageField"]
(* {{"litigation", "Noun"} -> {"jurisprudence", "law"}} *)

WordData["fighter", "UsageField"]
(*
{
 {"fighter", "Noun", "MilitaryPlane"} -> {"armed forces", "armed services", "military", "military machine", "war machine"}, 
 {"fighter", "Noun", "Shielder"} -> {}, 
 {"fighter", "Noun", "Individual"} -> {}
}
*)
```

There is also a `"WordNetID"` property.

```
WordData[{"fighter", "Noun", "MilitaryPlane"}, "WordNetID"]
(* {{"fighter", "Noun", "MilitaryPlane"} -> "03335030"} *)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar (and yet slightly different) to [a question I had](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/6457/library-containing-dictionary-definitions) a few days ago. I've started looking into the answer provided to me. Look into [WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).

It looks that it can be accessed via HTTP request which should get you XML or JSON formatted text. I know it's not CSV or straight up .TXT, but it's free and should give you an entire dictionary.

Alternatively, you can download the class libraries and have full access to the dictionary without being connected. Which, if you're querying the dictionary a lot (as I am), then you'll want to use this method to avoid being bogged down with internet connection. This should also ensure that any custom categorizations you create will not change if the online library changes.

Hope this helps.

Comment: WordNet contains word hierarchies but no categories.